# Most "linear" part of a function

Tags: derivatives, curves, linear-regression

I have an electricity problem in which I have to determine de most linear part of a function. I want to know if there is a way that I could determine this range via linear regression, differential calculus, or other. The function is $$f(x)=k\frac{x}{1-x} $$ for $x>0$ and $k$ constant. I do not study mathematics so thats why i come here, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what `most linear' exactly means, but my best bet would be to look at the first two terms (the linear part) of the Taylor expansion of this function at a point.

Comment: Which part of the function are you looking at? Only very small values of $x$ close to $0$? For very large (positive or negative) values of $x$, this function is very close to the constant function $g(x) = -k$.

Comment: The function can be well approximated by the linear function $x\mapsto kx$ in a neighbourhood of $x=0$. How large the neighbourhood can be depends on how good you want the approximation to hold ...

Comment: @Joppy, I'm looking for values beetween 0 and 0.5

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen, thanks for the answer! the problem is that if my range is small y get a better aproximation but also get worst resolution (I have to use a potentiometer to diggitaly vary this parameter) I dont know where is the optimum.

Comment: Do you want to bound the maximum error of the approximation, or the average error, or the average squared error, etc? Once you've chosen which one of these you want, there should be a straightforward answer as to what the "best" linear approximation over this range is.

Comment: @Joppy I don't want to bound the error, i want to minimize it in the way that i get sufficient resolution for a good measure, now i realize that responds my question, I need the parameters of the resolution of my microcontroller to answer this. Thanks!